# Is there a recommended way in order to have all information?

Tags: java

I aim to read in a XML file into Java (the coordinates of a polygon). And directly want to represent the polygon in a proper way to tackle a geometric question. Is this something I should do in the main method?

For reading in the XML file I created this code:

```
    public class ReadDataFromXmlFile throws IOException, SAXException, 
    ParserConfigurationException {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
      File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/instances/test_coordinates.xml");
      GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
      Polygon polygonFromCoordinates = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coordinates);
     }
```

However, my question is, how the polygon will be represented. Can I access x and y coordinates?

Maybe someone can give some clarification?

Thanks!

Comment: Parse xml in order to extract coordinates and send them via `createPolygon`  the on `var coordinates`. Before maybe it's better to made a direct example with predefined var to see how it's working, and how to add coords.

Comment: Thank you! Parse them into what exactly?

Comment: xml (a file) cannot be used as it is so extract coords and place them into `var coords`. Eg: `geometryFactory.createPolygon(geometryFa=
ctory.createLinearRing( new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(envelope.getMinX_XMLValue(), envelope.=getMinY_XMLValue()) ...`

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the proper way to read coordinates from an XML file is using String methods like find(), split(), etc. About doing it in main: of course in a separate method. What if you would like to read another file? And don't forget to use a try-catch!!

```
public static Polygon getPolygonFromFile(String filePath)
    File fXmlFile = null;
    Polygon resultPolygon = null; 
    try {
    // check here whether the file exists
    fXmlFile = new File(filePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // what to do if the file doesn't exist
    }
    // do what you need to create your Polygon
    return resultPolygon;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And for creating the Polygon I can use the above written code? 
   "GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
      Polygon polygonFromCoordinates = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coordinates);" ... 
because when it's a string it probably can't 'know' coordinates or is this no problem?

Comment: @C-lara what is **coordinates** that you pass to createPolygon()? You never declare it. In Java, each variable has a certain type that you cannot change easily like in Python. Check [here](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/GeometryFactory.html) for different parameters for createPolygon() and choose one you need. I suggest using Polygon constructor instead of geometryFactory. Check second constructor [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html)